# PowerBI Period Slicers (QTD/YTD) not slicing

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create period slicers for QTD/YTD/Last 12 Month (LTM) to create an interactive report dashboard.

I've set up all the Measures I think are required based on "Actual" data.

```
AC = SWITCH([PeriodSelect], 1, [AC Select], 2, [AC QTD], 3, [AC YTD], 4, [AC LTM])

AC LTM = CALCULATE([AC Select], DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], MAX('Calendar'[Date]),-12, MONTH))

AC QTD = CALCULATE([AC Select], DATESQTD('Calendar'[Date]))

AC Select = CALCULATE([AC Sum], Scenario[ScenarioName] = "Actual")

AC Sum = SUM(Actual[Value])
```

However, the slicer only shows the Values (AC). The [AC Select] is working fine, and I can slice it by Month and Year.  However, AC QTD/YTD/LTM remains blank.

There are no error messages and I do not know what is wrong.  I know the question is a bit vague but would appreciate if anyone can look it over https://www.dropbox.com/s/bavlq5h360ax27y/TestReport.pbix?dl=0

Comment: One mistake I've noticed is that you've chosen the wrong fields for Month and Year filters. They should come from Calendar table, not Actuals.

Comment: Thanks @RADO, I changed it but the YTD/QTD slicers still don't reflect what they are supposed to.  I suspect the issue is either in my [AC Sum] measure or something relating to the Actuals data (which is by month only, so all the Values are set to say Jan 1 2021 then Feb 1 2021).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, date slicers should be based on the calendar table, not actual dates.
Once you fix it, your formulas work correctly.

It might look like periods are not slicing, but that's not correct - they are. The reason you see the same numbers is because in your data sample, for March 2022, the results are the same for QTD, YTD and LTM periods.

This is how your data looks:

[image]

Notice that for QTD and YTD the numbers are the same because in March, you are in the first quarter, and the date interval is the same (Jan 1 2022 - March 31 2022). For later quarters, they will be different.

For LTM, the date interval is April 1, 2021 - March 31 2022, but in 2021 you only have data for January and February, so it's not included. As a result, the AC sum is the same.

To see that it's working, select January 2022 instead:

[image]

and the AC selector works fine too.